# collect2: fatal error: cannot find ‘ld’ compilation terminated

Tags: 22.04, compiling, symbolic-link, g++, binutils

I accidently overwrote the ld file in /usr/bin. I then removed the file and reinstalled binutils. Now I get the error in the title when I try to compile a C++ file with g++.

The ld file is present in the /usr/bin directory, although it looks like a broken symlink. It points to a file called x86_64-linux-gnu-ld, which I am unable to find anywhere. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`/usr/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu-ld` is itself a symbolic link, to `/usr/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu-ld.bfd`

```
$ ls -l /usr/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu-ld
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 23 Mar 12  2022 /usr/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu-ld -> x86_64-linux-gnu-ld.bfd
```

`/usr/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu-ld.bfd` is provided by the binutils-x86-64-linux-gnu package

```
$ dpkg -S $(realpath /usr/bin/ld)
binutils-x86-64-linux-gnu: /usr/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu-ld.bfd
```

So try re-installing binutils-x86-64-linux-gnu

Comment: It worked! Thanks a lot. Although the x86_64-linux-gnu-ld.bfd file was already present, re-installing the binutils-x86-64-linux-gnu package brought back the x86_64-linux-gnu-ld file.